# How to remove copy and define in a document when i open with UIDocumentInteractionController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, document

problem statement:   preventing the copy (copying text) functionality in iOS app `Document/PDF` Viewer **(.pdf, .doc, .docx, .txt & etc)**.

Description: 
Currently, We are developing an iOS app. as a part of app requirement we need to restrict the copy functionality. I am using `UIDocumentInteractionController` for previewing files **(.pdf, .doc, .docx, .txt & etc)** in my app. While previewing the file we need to restrict the copy (copying text) functionality.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should overrides the canPerformAction:withSender: method to return NO for actions that you don't want to allow:

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    if (action == @selector(paste:))
        return NO;
    if (action == @selector(copy:))   
        return NO;
    if (action == @selector(select:))   
        return NO;    
    if (action == @selector(selectAll:))   
        return NO;  
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

**OR you can try this also**

```
-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    UIMenuController *menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
    if (menuController) {
        [UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible = NO;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Hope this works for you. :)

Comment: I had already used this methods but not called when i select the text